# VxWorks Simulator Error: failed for simnet0

Tags: simulator, vxworks, wind-river-workbench

I am a beginner in VxWorks.
I use **Wind River Workbench 4** and **VxWorks-7** for VxWorks Development.
I start the VxWorks Simulator in Wind River Workbench Terminal with prebuilt VIP project located in */samples* directory.

---

The Terminal displays the following error:

> Error: ipcom_drv_eth_init :: endFindByName failed for IPv4, drv=simnet, unit=0, errorno=6d0002

I tried to search for relevant solutions, but no relevant solutions have been found.